# How to compare string date time in perl?

Tags: perl

I have this date time format in string "11:56:41, 11/22/2011".

Here's what I want:

Compare two date time strings like.

```
$date1 = "11:56:41, 11/22/2011";
$date2 = "11:20:41, 11/20/2011";
if($date2 < $date1) {
    do something...
} else {
    do nothing...
}
```

Any ideas how could i achieve this in perl?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An efficient method is to reorder the fields to something lexically comparable.

```
sub to_comparable {
   my ($date) = @_;
   my ($H,$M,$S,$d,$m,$Y) = $date =~ m{^([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}), ([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})\z}
      or die;
   return "$Y$m$d$H$M$S";
}

if (to_comparable($date2) lt to_comparable($date1)) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: since we don't know from the question whether single digit day/month/hour/minutes will be zero-padded, it might be better to return sprintf('%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d$02d',$Y,$m,$d,$H,$M,$S)

Comment: @bigiain I've encounter a little problem, just a simple question (I guess there's no need to make another one) how about if the date I was about to compare is a nonzero-padded?

Comment: @quinekxi, Then you use bigiain's sprintf instead of my concatenation. An adjustment must also be made to the regex.

Comment: @ikegami, Its okay now, I just need to format the dates before using the method.

Answer (score 15):

One more solution that uses the overloaded comparisons after converting the times to `Time::Piece` objects. Creating the objects may be overkill for something simple, but they can become very useful if you need to do other things with the times.

```
use Time::Piece;

my $dateformat = "%H:%M:%S, %m/%d/%Y";

my $date1 = "11:56:41, 11/22/2011";
my $date2 = "11:20:41, 11/20/2011";

$date1 = Time::Piece->strptime($date1, $dateformat);
$date2 = Time::Piece->strptime($date2, $dateformat);

if ($date2 < $date1) {
    do something...
} else {
    do nothing...
}
```

Comment: +1 for [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/JHI/perl-5.7.2/ext/Time/Piece/Piece.pm), a date management module which is already built into Perl

Answer (score 9):

What, already 4 hours and not a single [DateTime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime) (all hail the mighty [DateTime](http://datetime.perl.org)) answer in sight? You're slacking, [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) subscribers… ☻

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw();
my $p = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%T, %D', on_error => 'croak',);

my $date1 = $p->parse_datetime('11:56:41, 11/22/2011');
my $date2 = $p->parse_datetime('11:20:41, 11/20/2011');

if($date2 < $date1) {
    say "$date2 comes before $date1";
} else {
    say "$date2 does not come before $date1";
}
```

The method [`parse_datetime`](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) returns instances of `DateTime` whose comparison operators and stringification are overloaded to DTRT.

Comment: this works but unfornutely, my requirements is that i won't use an installed module except for the already in the package of installation of perl. anyways. thanks for your input :D

Comment: Because it's overkill for the job at hand.

Comment: @quinekxi, So code from StackOverflow is ok, but code from CPAN is not? How does that make any sense?

Comment: @ikegami What I mean is that I am required to compare the strings without using DateTime::Format::Strptime or any module that still needs to install. I don't know if I explain it right. But still daxim's code worked well to me.

Comment: @quinekxi, That doesn't change anything. You're still saying you're ok with installing code from StackOverflow, but not code from CPAN.

Comment: @ikegami I don't know where am I wrong, but sorry. Just a noob programmer-wanna-be asking for help. And yes, I am okay using preferred codes from someone i don't know and no, I am using CPAN. I guess I said it that way cuz i don't know how to install the modules from CPAN manually but not until yesterday that I've learned from another user the how's.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the datetimes (in your case these are local datetimes because they have no time zones) into ISO8601 then you can do regular string comparison.

To perform the conversion, you should extract the six components from your format

```
HH:MM:SS, mm/DD/YYYY
```

and reassemble them into ISO 8601:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
```

Then a normal lexicographic comparison will work.

See http://codepad.org/berle9um

Repeated here:

```
sub my_format_to_iso8601 {
    $_[0] =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d), (\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d\d\d)/;
    return "$6-$4-$5T$1:$2:$3";
}

$date1 = "11:56:41, 11/22/2011";
$date2 = "11:20:41, 11/20/2011";
$d1 = my_format_to_iso8601($date1);
$d2 = my_format_to_iso8601($date2);
print "first is $d1\n";
print "second is $d2\n";
if ($d2 < $d1) {
    print "second is earlier\n";
} else {
    print "first is earlier\n";
}
```

**ADDENDUM**

- ikegami's Perl code is much better.
- A date library would be your friend here; simply specify a format string and use the library's parse function to get your date object, which it should then be able to compare directly.  (That said, it is always fun to point out that ISO8601 is, by design, sortable in string form.)

Comment: thanks, it sure works for me. there's no big difference between your code and ikegami's. both worked well. :D

Answer (score 2):

I use unixtime. :)

I convert both times to unixtime and then I just have two integers to compare and so I can use the operators <, ==,  >  etc

e.g. convert to unixtime as follows

```
my $timestamp = "2014-03-25 12:33:32";  # (We assume localtime)

# 
# To split on the space character, it's best to use the regex / /
# 
my ($date, $time) = split (/ /, $timestamp);
my ($year, $mon, $mday) = split ('-', $date);
my ($hour, $min, $sec) = split (':', $time);

my $unixtime = timelocal($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon-1, $year);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this instance I've always used `Date::Calc`:

```
use Date::Calc;

my $date1 = "11:56:41, 11/22/2011";
my $date2 = "11:20:41, 11/20/2011";

my @date1arr=split /[^\d]/, $date1 if($date1 =~ m!\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}, \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}!;
my @date2arr=split /[^\d]/, $date2 if($date2 =~ m!\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}, \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}!;

my @diff = Delta_DHMS(@date1arr, @date2arr);
my $less;
foreach my $d ( @diff ) { $less = 1 if $d < 0; }

if($less) { ... }
```

Comment: That works, but Date::Calc is pretty heavyweight for the simple case here. ikegami's solution works (at least in the restricted problem space given in the question) just as well without needing to load all of Date::Calc (a perhaps insignificant ~300 or so ms on my machine here...)