# Reg Ex matching time range

Tags: regex, expression

I have a log file that saves logs by time stamp. What I have to do is to read certain values between time range. For example from the beginning of file and `5:3:55`. I am not good with regex was wondering how can I write expression to read it. So far I have come with following expression which is not right. Any samples how to write it properly? Thanks

```
([0-1]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d):([0-5]?\d)
```

The post that has the solution for range doesnt work for my needs as it is taking a range of time and dealing with files. While I need to go from start of file time stamp than certain increment than do certain word matches. Thanks

Comment: No, regular expressions are just the wrong tool for this. Try to solve it without them. Btw, where did you get that regex above from, it seems not related to your question?

Comment: is it just about the seconds?

Comment: This regex matches `0:0:0`, `00:00:00`, `23:59:59` etc. What is your requirement?

Comment: Do you use any programming language to accomplish this? If so, which one? Maybe it would be easier for you to compare the timestamp against a minimum and maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit more than a regex (at least to make a sane solution).  Here is a sample program that demonstrates a simple solution in Perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $time_min = '08:19:48';
my $time_max = '12:30:48';

while (1)
{
   print "enter time: ";

   chomp($_ = <STDIN>); 

   if (time_numeric($_) <= time_numeric($time_max) and
       time_numeric($_) >= time_numeric($time_min))
   {
        print "$_ is between $time_min and $time_max\n";
   }
   else
   {
        print "$_ ain't between $time_min and $time_max\n";
   }
}

sub time_numeric 
{
   if ($_[0] =~ /^(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})$/)
   {
        return ($3 + $2 * 100 + $1 * 10000);
   }
   else
   {
        die "Invalid time!";
   }
}
```

It doesn't bother to validate the time, simply assuming that the input is real times.  It also only works with 24 hour time stamps.

It does work with input whether or not it has leading zeros in the fields.

If you are working in Perl, also consider using a module such as `Time::Piece`, [as demonstrated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8222183/1919238).

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regular expressions for maths! You might use them to parse all dates (e.g. with the regex you included in your question), but then do the comparisons against your given timestamps with the parsed value. It's like comparing numbers lexically.

If you really needed a regex that matches every date between **5:3:34** and **5:3:55**, it would need to match all possible digits separately:

```
/5:3:(3[4-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-5])/
```